# WIndows 8 App, HTML/Javascript Offline Black Screen

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, winjs

I'm trying to develop a small Windows 8 App as a test for a larger project that I'll be working on.

I'm using VS 2012, HTML, CSS, and Javascript.    I've been able to create, build and deploy the app with out a problem, however I notice that if I put my tablet into airplane mode (i.e. take it offline) and then try to open the app, I just get a black screen.
Is there a "best practice" for handling offline scenarios?

I am familiar with using manifest for mobile web apps, but this doesn't seem matter here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `applicationData`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465118.aspx
Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/a5f0477d-c665-477e-b118-77446b7029ce

Comment: So what if I'm not concerned with storing data?  I would actually be pretty content with just recognizing that the app is offline and displaying a screen that says, "This app requires internet access"  Actually, anything other than a Black Screen would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use NetworkStatusChange event and take require action. this [quickstart at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700376.aspx) also documents the best practices.

You can try out some application from Microsoft like Store, news, music to give idea for offline behavior of your app.